# How to get contacts from Global Address List using c#

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm trying to get the lists of contacts from Outlook Global Address list (From my company emails, I think from Exchange) but I had an exception. I did this code:

```
Outlook.Application OutlookApplication = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.AddressLists addrLists = OutlookApplication.Session.AddressLists;
Outlook.AddressList gal = addrLists["Global Address List"];
foreach (Outlook.AddressEntry myentry in gal.AddressEntries)
{
    Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList listex = myentry.GetExchangeDistributionList();
    Outlook.AddressEntries entradas = listex.GetExchangeDistributionListMembers();
    for (int i = 0; i < entradas.Count; i++)
    {
        Outlook.AddressEntry exchDLMember = entradas[i];
        MessageBox.Show(exchDLMember.Name, "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
}
```

I got this exception, Object reference not established as an instance of an object, in the line:

```
Outlook.AddressEntries entradas = listex.GetExchangeDistributionListMembers();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that `GetExchangeDistributionList()` method returns null, and you never check for that. This behavior is expected as it only returns a valid object if you are dealing with a GAL distribution list.

For non-DL GAL entries, you need to use [GetExchangeUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry.getexchangeuser?view=outlook-pia) method. You must also always check that you get back a valid object rather than null.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get the contact.Email1Address, contact.Department, contact.FullName, contact.NickName. I can't read this in Outlook.AddressEntry exchDLMember

Comment: ContactItem is an object created on top of a message (not very different from the MAPI point of view from a regular mail item) that resides in the Contacts folder. GAL objects come from the Active Directory, *not* from your Contacts folder. Use AddressEntry.PrimarySmtpAddress, Name, etc.

Comment: Thanks but when I try to find PrimarySmtpAddress in Outlook.AddressEntry.PrimarySmtpAddress it appears an error, the type name PrimarySmtpAddress does not exist in the type AddressEntry. What would be the mistake?

Comment: Sorry, it is ExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress